# Weird noise coming out on Windows 7 when harddisk activity at peak?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm having a very strange problem.  I'm hearing a "choooooooooo kkkrrr" sound (Its not like the normal sound speakers make when powered on) all the time. When there is more Hard Disk r/w activity the sound increases and as HDD r/w activity slows down so the sound.

I have two other OS installed on my system. I have tested, it only happens when I'm on Windows 7. I have no clue what the hell is happening !? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the sample of noise:     http://www.ziddu.com/download/20852917/noise.mp3.html

Comment: attach an audio file if you can.

Comment: I would suspect interference your sound card picks up. Is this a Laptop?

Comment: You might be able to reduce the problem by cranking up your apps and lowering the overall system volume.

Comment: TheUser1024: Are you saying the noise is occurring because of applications I have installed ?!

Comment: Is this sound coming directly from the chassis, or from the speakers? If it's coming from the chassis, it may be from the HDD itself. Why when only using Windows? Because, some application in the Windows installation may be trying to access a file on a bad sector, leading to a sound from the HDD making several attempts to read that very sector.

Comment: Speakers. only from speakers. When I switch OS (Ubuntu or Fedora the noise disappears. No matter what I do, I dont find any problem there. Its only with Windows. Im certain of it.

Comment: Im on a desktop. I have a home theater and Head set. I have tested both. They are Ok.

Comment: There's a burst of noise at the end of that MP3 that might be honest file corruption, or worse (an exploit for some player that's not Google Chrome?) Also, Ziddu is very spammy, but then so is every file sharing site.

Comment: I had such thing when I used to digitize vinyl records from an old piece of hardware. Finally I've burnt down my Line-In, two weeks later internal audio died. During these two weeks I was hearing strange sounds from my headphones during some operations. There were sounds for peak activity and for idle too. Was interesting though...

Comment: have you checked to make sure that your microphone isn't picking up noise from the system? Check all your recording devices in sound manager. Disable all of them and see if it still happens.

Comment: Is this happening when you boot in Safe mode ?

Comment: @ harrymc: Did not tried the Safe mode. 
@Tharaka: Yes. I have checked that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Detach your faulty headset (if any).
2. Re-install/(Update) Realtek audio driver (if you were using it).
   ----------Thats all. My problem is gone now.

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused by corrupt audio driver.

Answer (score 0):

Backup all important data from your PC then open command prompt and type below command.

Chkdsk c: /f

Note:-C: is a drive letter and /f for fix errors, kindly run this command on all partitions one by one.

Thanks

Comment: That’s a pretty generic answer and only barely relevant. Did you intend it as a diagnostic step? If so, you have enough rep to have posted it as the comment it is instead of as an answer. Either way, you should have specified the `/r` switch to `chkdsk` instead.

Comment: I have done that, but the problem persists.